# Add More Metrics to Ray Tune Status Table (Python, PyTorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, hyperparameters, ray, ray-tune

When running `tune.run()` on a set of configs to search, is it possible to add more metrics columns (i.e. `a`, `b`, etc) to the status table being printed out?

```
tune.track.log(a=metric1, b=metric2)
```

will give the following table without columns for the metrics `a` and `b`:

```
== Status ==
Memory usage on this node: 22.1/125.8 GiB
Using FIFO scheduling algorithm.
Resources requested: 1/32 CPUs, 1/4 GPUs, 0.0/65.59 GiB heap, 0.0/22.13 GiB objects
Result logdir: /home/nyxynyx/ray_results/fooba
Number of trials: 4 (3 PENDING, 1 RUNNING)
+--------------+----------+-------+------+-----+
| Trial name   | status   | loc   |   lr |   x |
|--------------+----------+-------+------+-----|
| fooba_00000  | RUNNING  |       | 0.01 |   1 |
| fooba_00001  | PENDING  |       | 0.1  |   1 |
| fooba_00002  | PENDING  |       | 0.01 |   5 |
| fooba_00003  | PENDING  |       | 0.1  |   5 |
+--------------+----------+-------+------+-----+
```

How can we include a column for every metric that we pass to `tune.track.log()` other than `mean_accuracy`?

*Using Python 3.7.3 and Ray 0.8.4*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! You should be able to do this with a reporter object: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune/api_docs/reporters.html